# When I going to run my android application the emulator in Genymotion doesn't show

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, genymotion

[When I going to run my android application the emulator in Genymotion doesn't show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqg32.png)

Comment: Try following commands: 1.`adb kill-server` 2.`adb start-server` to restart adb.

Answer (score 1):

go to tools->android->enable abd integration.when you open your genymotion emulator.just disable the abd integration first and then re-enable it.